# How can I monitor BizTalk Receive Location Polling?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-2010

I am trying to monitor the ftp and sql polling receive locations in BizTalk 2009 and BizTalk 2010.

I want to know how often a receive location is polling, when the last time the poll took place, how long the poll took, and did the poll create a message. I can see the messages that are created when the poll is complete. I am more interested in the polling itself.

What screen or tool can I use to see this information? Can I find this information in the BizTalk database tables?

Answer (score 2):

How often a receive location is polling will depend on the "Polling settings" you configure on the receive location. Ex: on FTP configuration there is a section called "Polling Setting" with Interval and Units.

I'm afraid there is no direct way to figure out "Did the poll created a message". If in case it retrieved a message, then you would have seen the details of the service instance with the message, but if in case it didn't pulled any message then there won't be any trace. This will apply to "last time the poll took place" as well

Again, I don't thing you will get details for "How long the poll took".

Answer (score 1):

You could dig into using [WMI for BizTalk](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisromp/archive/2008/04/02/using-wmi-to-monitor-send-ports-and-receive-locations-in-biztalk-server.aspx).  I know you can get a hold of the locations status but I'm not sure about some of the other things you want.  I belive MOM using WMI so I suppose its possible to do the same thing.